# [ERLANG]: Creating a webclient using Riak and Erlang in back-end

Tags: erlang, webclient, middleware, riak, nosql

I want to somehow connect my riak database to a website using Erlang. I have some data stored within my database but I can't quite make the connection between the two, to configure the middleware which will enable this to happen. What I have tried so far is following this tutorial

http://buffered.io/posts/webmachine-erlydtl-and-riak-part-1/

which basically uses Webmachine and erlyDTL for this purpose but it seems a bit circumstantial... my question is, is there any simpler way of doing this? Or any proven way that the stackoverflow community knows of? I mean, how do I query things from the riak database to a website? A bit confused on how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Whatever](https://www.google.pl/search?q=erlang+web+framework&oq=erlang+web&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i59l2j69i60j0.3387j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8&qscrl=1) [webserver](https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/ChicagoBoss/wiki/Comparison-of-Erlang-Web-Frameworks) you are using, you always can/should use [riak-erlang-client](https://github.com/basho/riak-erlang-client).  And this is excatly approach that post you mentioned uses.

Or if you don't really know Erlang you can use any [other client basho prvides](https://github.com/basho?query=client).